# How can I create an initialize a vector in one expression?

Tags: c++, stl, tbb

I would like to create an initialize a Container (like a vector or list) without declaring a new variable?

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
tbb::parallel_do(v, lambda);
```

Instead, I'd like something like:

```
tbb::parallel_do({1}, lambda);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tbb::parallel_do`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506158) is a template, and the first parameter is a bare template parameter. In conjunction with the fact that `{1}` is not an expression and thus doesn't have a type, there is no way to deduce the template parameter and so that is not possible.

But, `std::vector` has a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list`, meaning that you can directly initialize the vector with a list of elements. This in turns means that you can write:

```
tbb::parallel_do(std::vector{1}, lambda);
```

And the temporary vector will contain the only element that you added in your original example. Most containers supports this kind of initialization, so for most of them you should be fine. If for some reason the one you want doesn't, you can create a helper function that will do it for you.

Comment: @Slava If you want to. OP didn't specify a version so I'm going with C++17 :P

Comment: Our compiler version supports C++17 but it's not enabled. It works though. Great answer and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following overload of [`std::vector`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

```
explicit vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Here's how to use it.

```
tbb::parallel_do(std::vector<int>(1, 1), lambda);
```